# Retrieve date value from database to jdatechooser

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdatechooser

I have a form on which I want to access a date from the database and show in jDateChooser for a particular record. How do I get the date from the database table and how do I set that date in jDateChooser? The datatype on my database is date.

```
 JDateChooser.setText(a.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 5).toString());
```

this is my code and it produces error.

Answer (score 0):

First what is "a"? For the looks It seems to be a Table(?)

By JDateChooser you mean the netbeans plugin? or the JDateChooser from Toedter? or anything else?

You really should provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

If you have a JDateChooser from Toedter then you can use something like

```
JDateChooser.setDate(<Date_from_DB>)
```

With this little info I can't help you more

Comment: a is the DefaultTableModel. The thing that I want to happen is that, when i clicked a row in a JTable, the date in that row will be displayed in the JDateChooser. And yes, it is from Toedter.